# Validating the presence of a column on a join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is a fairly common issue but I couldn't find a solution. My domain has two models, Company and ExternalLink (a representation of a social media provider like Facebook or Twitter). The join model, CompaniesExternalLink, has the direct URL to a social media account (ie http://www.facebook.com/goldmansachs). I need to validate the presence of that URL, but the join is created on the association, which breaks and returns ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Any advice would be great. Sample code below:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :companies_external_links
    has_many :external_links, through: :companies_external_links, dependent: :destroy

end

class ExternalLink < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :companies_external_links
    has_many :companies, through: :companies_external_links, dependent: :destroy

end

class CompaniesExternalLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :url, presence: true
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :external_link

    validates :external_link, uniqueness: {scope: :company_id}
end
```

The relevant parts of the schema.rb

```
create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "state"
  t.string   "logo"
  t.string   "slug"
  t.text     "description"
end

create_table "companies_external_links", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "external_link_id"
  t.string   "url"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end


create_table "external_links", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "source"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "icon"
end
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your schema? I'd like to know what's in the external_links table since url is in the companies_external_links table.

Comment: Updated the original comment. `source` on `external_links` is a string name of the social network, such as "Facebook" or "LinkedIn"

Comment: What does the validation error say is the problem with the associated record (look at .errors array on the ActiveRecord object)?

Comment: Trying to create the association manually in Rails Console and saving it without a URL gave the below:

=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9b204edd70 @base=#<CompaniesExternalLink id: nil, company_id: 9, external_link_id: 3, url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:url=>["can't be blank"]}>

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you're not running into a problem with not permitting the param (strong parameters)? You're going to have to debug why the url attribute is blank.

Comment: Oh, I should be clear - the URL param is blank because we're assigning the relationship in an admin panel. We're using RailsAdmin and giving a company an external link. If it was via a form, I could use nested attributes, yes?

Comment: Yes, you could. Are you saying that you a manually creating the ExternalLink (e.g., by building it on the external_links association of Company)? Are you then making sure that you set the url attribute of the related CompaniesExternalLink to be non-blank before saving? If not then that's the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49169/discussion-between-nikhilthomas90-and-coenwulf)